# Mouseover Div and Show Inner Div Safari Parrent Height Issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

Please take a look at this site:

http://bstgllc.com

In Safari, I cannot get the div's to remain in place when the user mouses over them. They are intended to just change the margin top of their inner divs so they creep up into view. I've used both jQuery and CSS to achieve the same effect which works in other browsers, but Safari seems to continue on with this bug.

Hope someone out there has had this same issue!

Comment: could you create a fiddle replicating this issue? That way we can look through and debug your javascript.

Comment: manipulating the margins via an animation may cause problems that a simple jQuery `.slideToggle()` may not experience. jQuery does a lot of the visual-bug-quirk fixing for you in some cases, such as animations. example code and fiddle would really help though.